# Infrared microwave

Tags: cooking

Microwaves are very efficient because they heat the food much more than the (highly reflective) walls of the oven. However, they heat the food throughout and thus won't make a nice crisp.

Most metals are also near perfect reflectors in the thermal infrared as well. Infrared light heats and crisps food much like hot air and can be generated with an incandescent filament at nearly 100% efficiency.

Would an infrared oven, using reflective walls, be an efficient replacement of a conventional or toaster oven? A microwave is high power but cooks for a very short time. This oven would take as long as a toaster oven to cook but hopefully would use much less power because most of the energy ends up in the food.

Comment: How would this "infrared oven" be any different from a conventional oven?  Especially an electric oven which has a big incandescent filament generating infrared light (radiant heat).

Comment: @Mark: In a conventional oven the whole oven gets very hot. Don't touch the walls! But having *reflective* polished metal walls will ideally keep the oven itself cool (except the filament of course) and like a microwave the heat will bounce around until it finds the food.